# Userform checkbox questions

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, userform

So I used the coding suggested and it wasn't working.  So I edited and clarified it a bit hoping that maybe my document was just being really picky but that isn't working either.  My entire code for that section is below.  Can anyone help me understand why this isn't working?

The lines below begin with moving textbox fields to my database and then my database does some calculations.  Those calculations return either a "T" or "F".  My userform then retrieves that information and if the fields are "T", then the checkboxes are checked in the userform in real time.  I am attempting to make my coding disable a checkbox that does not have a "T" and is not checked so it cannot be marked in the userform.  I do, however, need the user to be able to removes checkmarks from checkboxes that have a "T" behind them and are checked.

My code that I have is below and it is not disabling checkboxes that are not checked and do not have the "T" behind them.

````
' When time is entered, time transfers immediately to spreadsheet datafield and sends back to userform which meals are allowed.

Dim TargetRow As Integer
TargetRow = Sheets("Codes").Range("D43").Value + 1

With Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 26)
 .Value = TimeValue(txtArrivalTime)
 .NumberFormat = "hh:mm" 'arrival time
End With

'''MEALS ALLOWED PER SPREADSHEET TO USERFORM'''
With Me.chkMorning
    If Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 28).Value = "T" Then
        .Value = Checked
    Else
        .Value = Unchecked
        .Enabled = False
    End If
End With

With Me.chkMidday
    If Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 30).Value = "T" Then
        .Value = Checked
    Else
        .Value = Unchecked
        .Enabled = False
    End If
End With

With Me.chkEvening
    If Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 32).Value = "T" Then
        .Value = Checked
    Else
        .Value = Unchecked
        .Enabled = False
    End If
End With```
````

Comment: Use the events of the checkboxes and if they are checked then continue, if not cancel the action.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the checkboxes the user is not eligible to use:

```
If Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 28).Value = "T" Then
    frmUserTravel.chkMorning = Checked
Else
    frmUserTravel.chkMorning = Unchecked
    frmUserTravel.chkMorning.Enabled = False
End If
If Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 30).Value = "T" Then
    frmUserTravel.chkMidday = Checked

Else
    frmUserTravel.chkMidday = Unchecked
    frmUserTravel.chkMidday.Enabled = False
End If

If Sheets("Travel Expense Voucher").Range("Data_Start").Offset(TargetRow, 32).Value = "T" Then
    frmUserTravel.chkEvening = Checked
Else
    frmUserTravel.chkEvening = Unchecked
    frmUserTravel.chkEvening.Enabled = False
End If
```

Comment: This will allow them to uncheck a checked box but not allow them to check an unchecked box?  LOL  That was a mouthful.  :)   Does that make sense?

Comment: It will uncheck the boxes and prevent them from doing anything with them (not quite the same thing). Boxes they are allowed to change can be checked and unchecked at will (which is way more user friendly than *just* allowing to uncheck them)

Comment: Oh, so you are saying that if they are unchecked, they can't do anything but if they are checked, they can leave them or uncheck them.  Is that right?

Comment: If the condition doesn't apply, then the check box will be unchecked and disabled, preventing the user from changing them. If the condition does apply, the check box will be checked by default and can be changed at will. best you try the code

Comment: Will do, thank you so much for your help.  :)  I'll let you know here if I have any further questions!!

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this isn't working?  I used your code and that didn't work?  It isn't keeping me from checking boxes that weren't supposed to be checked. Can you help me?  I can't attach my code here as I don't have enough characters.  It also doesn't format appropriately.  So I'm going to update the code in my first post.

Comment: It is usually better to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59721164/edit) instead of adding code in comments. Some screen caps may also be useful

Comment: I have edited my question and coding, however, I wasn't sure what you meant by 'screen caps'.  I'm sorry.  :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205952/discussion-between-cybernetic-nomad-and-kristen).

Comment: Cybernetic and I haven't been able to figure out yet what is going on.  If anyone else has any suggestions, I would be very appreciative.  :)

Comment: My problem is solved!  Thank you so much for all of your help, Cybernetic!  I received help from another forum and promised I would post the solution here.  I will update my code above to include what finally ended up working for me.  :)  I would have never gotten as close as I was though, without the help of Cybernetic!!  You are truly a genius! :)